# Delete Same Table Across Many Databases

Tags: mysql, sequelpro

I currently run a large network of WordPress installs that utilize many similar plugins.  I am attempting to cleanup some old tables but since each install has it's own database, I was wondering how I can utilize a query or Sequel Pro to achieve deleting by table name across each database if that table is found within the database.

Thanks.

Comment: All on the same machine?

Comment: Yes. They are all on the same server.